# Joining Two Tables with MY Model

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am using **Jamie Rumbelow's MY_model** and I'm trying to figure out how to get a single value from a second table through a join. What I am wanting to do is get all users and do a join that will retrieve the status_name so when I can display the results of the query I can just do

```
foreach ($users AS $user) {
    echo $user->status_name;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

```
user_id   username    status_id    role_id
-------------------------------------------
1         testuser1   1 (active)   1 (guest)
2         testuser2   1            2 (user)
3         testuser3   1            3 (editor)
4         testuser4   1            4 (admin)

status_id   status_name
-----------------------
1           active 
2           inactive
3           suspended
4           banned
5           deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select('table1.user_id, table1.username, table2.status_name, table1.role_id');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.status_id = table1.status_id');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

or this

```
$this->load_table('table1');
$this->load_table('table2');
$this->model_name->related('table2', array('status_id', 'status_id'));

$user=$this->model_name->get(
            array(
              'feilds'=>array(user_id,username,status_name,role_id)
            )
             );
```

Comment: This I know but is there an easier way with the MY_Model?

Comment: I dont think MY_Model classes doesnt support multiple tables and joins

Comment: try the 2nd code ... i am not sure about it, but give it a try